# Most recent posts drupal 8

Tags: views

I'm working on news portal using drupal 8. 
I need to display most recent posts but there is a little tricky thing.
In that view should be most recent news including updated ones, BUT not if we edited the node because of grammar errors, just if we are adding new information in that post or changing the news in it. 
I have '**updated field**' in post edit page [image: updated field]where we enter the time of post update so I can use that for sorting also... We fill this field only if we update the news with new information like live blog or something like that. 

 So, there is **authored on** (creation date) sort option, and **node change** sort option in drupal 8, but my problem is that I don't want to get posts that are updated because of grammar errors... 

Does anybody have some suggestions?
 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the view by the node created date, instead of the changed date.

Alternatively, you can add a date field to the node, "Published on", and use that instead. Drupal won't touch this field.

Comment: I take the OP wants a list of nodes for which new information is added, not the ones edited to fix grammar errors.

Comment: yes, most recent information on the site! If you change the grammar there is no new information there :)

Comment: You need your own date field then that you control.

Comment: I have it, 'updated field'... But it is null if we don't update anything and therefore I can't use it to sort posts...

Comment: Because you have to supply the data yourself. There's really no other way to do this.

Comment: Still thinking for some ways to solve this... Thanks anyway!

Comment: How else can this be solved without your own date fields? Drupal has no context over what is changing, therefore created/changes cannot be used here. The user has to supply the date value.

Comment: I don't know right now... I have other solutions to accomplish this, just need to see what will be suitable for our needs...

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty straightforward as it goes:

1. Add a Boolean checkbox field to the content type, label it, "last edit was trivial", or similar
2. Make sure your content editors are aware they need to tick/untick the field when appropriate
3. Add the new field to your filters; done

Comment: This is the only solution I could think of. There isn't a way to automatically know the edits where just grammar corrections.

Comment: This will work for edited (either way) posts, but will not display new posts that are not edited... Just think about news portal... We need 'most recent' section with most recent published news and updated news (only if publishers writing about live event). Thanks for suggestion, it is still helpful! :)